# Swift 3 Playground on XCode 8 "Ambiguous reference to member 'joined()' Error

Tags: xcode, swift3

I have the Dictionary:

```
let alphabet: [Character: Int] = ["a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2, "d": 3]

let validSet = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: alphabet.keys.joined())
```

and that's when I get the error. How could I fix this and Why is it happening?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to change your key type to String as already suggested, then `map` the Characters to Strings:

```
let alphabet: [Character: Int] = ["a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2, "d": 3]
let validSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: alphabet.keys.map{String($0)}.joined())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it. Any clue why my question was downvoted? I don't think not knowing that `joined()` is for `String` only is a common thing is it O_0 ?

Comment: @lokilindo upvoted. It's always unpleasant feeling to be downvoted by a stranger who hasn't even posted a reason.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you should change to make it work is the type of keys, from `Character` to `String`:

```
let alphabet: [String: Int] = ["a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2, "d": 3]
let validSet = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: alphabet.keys.joined())
```